# Convert a Set of to Integer

Tags: delphi

As a newbie in Delphi I run into a problem with an external API. 
This external API expects a parameter with one or two value, I think called bitwise parameter. 
In Delphi this is done by a **set of**

The basic is an Enumeration.

```
TCreateImageTask = (
  citCreate = 1,
  citVerify
);
```

This I have put into a set of:

```
TCreateImageTasks = set of TCreateImageTask
```

In a function I fill this set with:

```
function TfrmMain.GetImageTask: TCreateImageTasks;
begin
    Result:=[];
    if chkCreate.checked then Include(Result, citCreate);
    if chkVerify.checked then Include(Result, citVerify);
end;
```

Now I have to give this Tasks to a external DLL, written in C++
The DLL expects a **__int8** value. It may contain one or two  TCreateImageTasks. In C++ done by:

```
__int8 dwOperation = 0;

   if (this->IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_CHECK_CREATE))
   {
      dwOperation = BS_IMGTASK_CREATE;
   }

   if (this->IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_CHECK_VERIFY))
   {
      dwOperation |= BS_IMGTASK_VERIFY;
   }

int32 res = ::CreateImage(cCreateImageParams, dwOperation);
```

So I have to convert my set of to an integer. I do by

```
function TfrmMain.SetToInt(const aSet;const Size:integer):integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Move(aSet, Result, Size);
end;
```

I call with

```
current task := GetImageTask;
myvar := SetToInt(currentTask, SizeOf(currentTask));
```

The problem I have now, that myvar is 6 when 2 values are inside the set, 2 if only create is inside the set and 4 if only verify is inside the set. That do not look right to me and the external DLL do not know this values.

Where is my fault?

Comment: You don't seem to know what "flags" are and how a byte can combine 8 bits: `2 or 4` makes `iValue= 6` and any code is still able to test against `if iValue and 2<> 0 then` . Creating an ENUM is wrong and seems to be entirely your idea, not the one of the API.

Comment: Sorry, the enum is out of the API. So there is still the question why the Enum citCreate is 1 but after put into an integer Is 2. I also think this is nothing about flags, because I also testes with a naked simple Delphi form without any special setting, just defaults.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it works when you remove the `= 1` in the declaration of `TCreateImageTask`?

The `= 1` shifts the ordinal values by 1 giving the results you see, but is probably not what is needed. For that we need to know the values for `BS_IMGTASK_CREATE` and `BS_IMGTASK_VERIFY`.

My psychic powers tell me that `BS_IMGTASK_CREATE = 1` and `BS_IMGTASK_VERIFY = 2`. Given that these are bit masks they correspond to the values `2^0` and `2^1`. This matches the ordinal values 0 and 1.

Thus you should declare

```
TCreateImageTask = (citCreate, citVerify);
```

to map `citCreate` to 0 and `citVerify` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

**It's all about something called Bitwise Operation!**

Converting a SET to LONGWORD is widely used in Delphi implementation of Windows API.

This would be what you are looking for:

[How to save/load Set of Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9553510/1049870)

This was already answered here too:

[Bitwise flags in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3728141/1049870)