# Algorithm for hashing/encoding multiple values into a single integer value

Tags: algorithm, winapi, encoding, hash, encode

There is this algorithm for "hashing" or encoding multiple values into a single integer, by assigning exponentially increasing numeric value to individual values. This approach was in particular used in Windows DLLs.

A possible use case can be a client application requesting a list of items matching certain status codes from an API.

For example, if we have the following values:

```
* open
* assigned
* completed
* closed
```

...we assign a numeric value to each:

```
* open - 1
* assigned - 2
* completed - 4
* closed - 8
```

etc. where each following value is 2x the previous.

**Encoding**

When we need to pass a combination of any of these values, we add up the corresponding numeric values. For example, for "open, assigned" it is `3`, for "assigned, completed, closed" it is `14`. This covers all of the unique combinations. As we can see, the "encoding" part is very straightforward.

**Decoding**

To decode the value, the only way I can think of is switch..case statements, like so (pseudocode):

```
1 = open
2 = assigned
3 = open + assigned
4 = completed
5 = open + completed
6 = assigned + completed
7 = open + assigned + completed
8 = closed
9 = open + closed
10 = assigned + closed
11 = open + assigned + closed
12 = completed + closed
13 = open + completed + closed
14 = assigned + completed + closed
15 = open + assigned + completed + closed
```

This algorithm obviously works under the following assumptions:

- only works when each value is used only once
- only works when both sides know the matching numeric values

**Questions:**

1. What is a more optimal way/algorithm to "decode" the values instead of the very elaborate switch..case statements?
2. Is there a name for this algorithm?

Note: the question is tagged with `winapi` mostly for discoverability. The algorithm is fairly universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is formally known as a [bit mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728018/), where each bit in an integer is assigned a meaning.  Bits are assigned numeric values that are powers of 2 in binary (bit0=2<sup>0</sup>=1, bit1=2<sup>1</sup>=2, bit2=2<sup>2</sup>=4, bit3=2<sup>3</sup>=8, etc).

You can use the `OR` and `AND` [logical bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators) to set/query individual bits in an integer, eg:

```c
const DWORD State_Open = 1;
const DWORD State_Assigned = 2;
const DWORD State_Completed = 4;
const DWORD State_Closed = 8;

void DoSomething(DWORD aStates)
{
  ...

  if (aStates & State_Open)
    // open is present
  else
    // open is not present

  if (aStates & State_Assigned)
    // assigned is present
  else
    // assigned is not present

  if (aStates & State_Completed)
    // completed is present
  else
    // completed is not present

  if (aStates & State_Closed)
    // closed is present
  else
    // closed is not present

  ...
}
```

```c
DWORD lState = State_Open | State_Assigned | State_Completed | State_Closed;
// whatever combination you need ...
DoSomething(lState);
```

In Delphi/Pascal, this is better handled using a [`Set`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) instead, which is internally implemented as a bit mask, eg:

```pascal
type
  State = (State_Open, State_Assigned, State_Completed, State_Closed);
  States = Set of State;

procedure DoSomething(aStates: States);
begin
  ...

  if State_Open in aStates then
    // open is present
  else
    // open is not present

  if State_Assigned in aStates then
    // assigned is present
  else
    // assigned is not present

  if State_Completed in aStates then
    // completed is present
  else
    // completed is not present

  if State_Closed in aStates then
    // closed is present
  else
    // closed is not present

  ...
end;
```

```pascal
var
  lState: States;
begin
  ...
  lState := [State_Open, State_Assigned, State_Completed, State_Closed];
  // whatever combination you need ...
  DoSomething(lState);
  ...
end;
```